# Database files to store objects

Tags: java, arrays, file, serialization

I need to store objects in files (.txt, .mio, .Whatever)

I'm using java

I have tried to implement the Serialize class to serialize objects and then store them, but I could not get the desired result.

**EDIT**

The idea is to store multiple objects in the same file and then open the file and look for a specific object, manipulate objects. etc.
it is as if it were a SQL database only with objects stored in files.

which would be a solution to this? a way of storing objects in files and then you can call them, search for them, store them in an array.

Would appreciate any idea and help.

**CODE**

```
   import java.io.Serializable;

public class Contacto implements Serializable {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;

    public Contacto(String nombre, String apellido){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido(){
        return this.apellido;
    }

    public void setNombre(String n){
        this.nombre = n;
    }

    public void setApellido(String a){
        this.apellido = a;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.getApellido() +" "+ this.getNombre();
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import java.io.*;

public class Serializador{

    // Escribe un objecto en un archivo
    private ObjectOutputStream escritorArchivo;

    // Lee un objecto que este guardado en un archivo
    private ObjectInputStream lectorArchivo;


    // Al metodo le pasamos el objeto que queremos serializar y lo guardará en el archivo que se le especifique al FileOutputStream (en este caso "objeto.mio")
    public void escribirArchivo(Object objeto){
        try{
            escritorArchivo = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("objeto.mio"));
            escritorArchivo.writeObject(objeto);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfex){
            fnfex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ioex){
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Object leerArchivo(String rutaArchivo){
        Object lectura = null;
        try{
            lectorArchivo = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(rutaArchivo));
            lectura = lectorArchivo.readObject();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfex){
            fnfex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ioex){
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex){
            cnfex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lectura;
    }

}
```

the code shows how the basic idea, however it is an idea that can be discarded.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you paste your code .. to get more clarity on what you are looking for?

Comment: @mhasan see de edit

Comment: you code seems to perform the logic of reading and writing the object state to file. Are you looking for converting and storing it as json format in the file?

Comment: no, sorry if I did misunderstand.
what I want is to store multiple objects in a file and then be able to open that file and make search, call an object in specific and suchlike.

Comment: Hi @Reco, this post should help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470138/writing-many-java-objects-to-a-single-file