# How can I serialize objects in a java application to more than one file?

Tags: java, object, serializable

Its a general question I am trying to deal with.

I used to program in java and just to implement the serializable.io interface in my sysData class inside my model package and then in the view Package I would just look for a single file ".ser" and either load or save into it.

But now, I want some of my classes to be saved into one ".ser" file and the others to another separate ".ser" file and I can't seem to find a way to figure that out.

I would be grateful if someone can hint me out on the concept of how to save some objects into one ".ser" file and the other bulk of objects to a different ".ser" file.

Thank you,

Tom

Comment: have a look may be it will give yo an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470138/writing-many-java-objects-to-a-single-file

Comment: Unless Java serialization is required, another serialization format may be worth looking into. The process will be similar in both cases: open a different serializer using a different output stream and write the given object graph to the appropriate serializer. Trying to process the serialized stream itself will .. not be fun.

Comment: We have good experience using [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/) instead of vanilla serialization.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.io.Serializable` interface allows you to save your data object to a data stream. This stream could be a file or any other persistent storage form or even send it over the network.

Have each of the classes you want to store implement the `Serializable` interface. Then use some sort of a mapping that knows which Class/object needs to be saved to which file.

For example,

```
A.class = A.ser
B.class = B.ser
C.class = C.ser
... and so on ...
```

Use this to save it and load data between the JVM and the file system.

Hope this helps!